# Swift 4.2) Mutate array of struct with for_in/forEach vs. access by index

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-structs

I am trying to modify struct element in array. I found that you can do that by accessing(iterate) the struct by index, but you can't if you use 'for in' loop or forEach{}.

```
struct Person
{
  var age = 0
  var name = "James"
}

var personArray = [Person]()
personArray += [Person(), Person(), Person()]


personArray.forEach({$0.age = 10}) // error: "Cannot assign to property: '$0' is immutable"

for person in personArray { 
  person.age = 10 // error: "Cannot assign to property: 'person' is a 'let' constant"
}


for index in personArray.indices {
  personArray[index].age = 10 // Ok
}
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: because this is an array of struct not class 
Class pass by ref and struct pass by value

Answer (score 24):

As stated in other answers you can't mutate in a `for-in` loop or in a `.forEach` method.

You can either use your last formulation which is short and concise:

```
for index in personArray.indices {
    personArray[index].age = 10
}
```

Or mutate the orignal `personArray` entirely:

```
personArray = personArray.map { person in 
    var person = person // parameter masking to allow local mutation
    person.age = 10
    return person
}
```

Note that the second option may seems less efficient as it creates a new instance of `Person` each time but Swift seems to be well optimised for those cases.

Here is a bonus if you really want a mutating counterpart for `.forEach` method :

```
extension MutableCollection {
    mutating func mutateEach(_ body: (inout Element) throws -> Void) rethrows {
        for index in self.indices {
            try body(&self[index])
        }
    }
}
```

This is a wrapper around array mutation equivalent to your first formulation, you can use it like intended:

```
personArray.mutateEach { $0.age = 10 }
```

Answer (score 6):

In Swift a struct is a **value** type. In the for or foreach loop the person item is a value, and if it were mutable you would only be changing a copy of the original, not the original as you intend.

If you really want an updatable reference to the **struct** inside the loop add a var keyword, but remember you are updating a copy not the original.

```
for var person in personArray {
    person.age = 10 // updates a copy, not the original
}
```

By contrast class is a **reference** type and in the loop each item is a reference to the original. Updating this reference value now updates the original.

Change your definition of Person to class instead of struct and it will work as expected.
For a complete explanation see https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html